# Comic female protagonist, pretty sure a goddess?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I've been searching for a urban fantasy comic/graphic novel series that I used to read when I was younger, in the last 8 years. It featured a female protagonist who was a goddess I'm pretty sure. It was set in modern times, but I think there was another world she could return to? All I can remember is it having stunning artwork of the characters, and the storylines were relatively dark. I would love some help figuring out what it was!

Comment: Got any more info?

Answer (score 16):

I'm pretty certain that you're thinking of [Aria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_%28comics%29) - written by Brian Holguin and featuring art by Jay Anacleto.

Anacleto's interior art was fantastic, but his cover art was far more detailed and jaw-droppingly gorgeous.

[image]

It was first published in 1999 and ran on-and-off through 2003. The main character, Aria was a Faerie princess who lives in New York running a book shop and traveled to hidden magic kingdoms. Various other gods, goddesses and faeries also live in NY.

According to [the Amazon description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158240139X), The concept was

> Somewhere around the corner, just beyond the edge of perception, lies a world you never dreamed existed...A world where creatures of ancient myth and gods long thought dead walk unnoticed along the crowded streets of Manhattan. Where ladies of Faerie dance lonely nights away, bathed in soft neon glare. Where every shadow holds a secret, and every secret has a price. Where danger and wonder can be found at any turn, if you only know where to look. Welcome to the World of...Aria.

Comment: OMG you are amazing phantom42! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Nadia please, accept the answer from phantom42 if it was accurate.